# Openseadragon rotate fabricjscanvas with viewer

Tags: fabricjs, openseadragon

i have implemented drawing tool in in openseadragon with fabricjscanvas but i am not able to rotate the fabricCanvas when origional image is being rotated, please help me about this PLease check this

https://github.com/MMtechnolab/OpenseadragonfabricjsDemo

Comment: Does this address your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456171/fabric-canvas-changing-position-when-openseadragon-image-is-rotated

Comment: i have tried that solution but not working also tried to rotate using css but didnt get much seccess

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows more about Fabric can help here...